# unique entries in a string array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I have a cell array, where each cell is a string of the following form:

```
A{1} = hello, world, the, hello, the, how, are, you, world
```

I would like to retain only the unique words, to give me a new char array that will go into an output cell array:

```
B{1} = hello, world, the, how, are, you
```

`unique()` does not seem to cut it. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: How have you tried to use `unique`? If used in the proper way it should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with some previous comments on questioning why the data is in this format (if you have a choice).

However:

```
>> A{1} = 'hello, world, the, hello, the, how, are, you, world';
>> B{1} = strjoin(unique(strtrim(strsplit(A{1}, ','))), ', ')

B = 

    'are, hello, how, the, world, you'
```

Hope that helps.

*** EDIT *** another solution that removes strtrim if you know there will always be a space. Also, if you do not want the operation to sort the strings you can use a 'stable' call to unique:

```
>> B{1} = strjoin(unique(strsplit(A{1}, ', '),'stable'), ', ')

B = 

    'hello, world, the, how, are, you'
```

Comment: Seems a cleaner solution than mine but I didn't remember the strsplit function. In fact I'm running 2012b so I don't have this function. strsplit is available from release 2013a.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried the strsplit() version, and it is exactly what I needed. As to answer the question as to why the data was in this format, it was given to me that way, and I do not have control over it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that A{1} is one long string.

```
A{1} = 'hello, world, the, hello, the, how, are, you, world';
```

In which case unique will just return the string or characters.

```
>> unique(A)
ans = 
    'hello, world, the, hello, the, how, are, you, world'

>> unique(A{:})
ans =
    ,adehlortuwy.
```

The string needs to be converted to a cell array first.

```
>> a = textscan(A{1},'%s','delimiter',',')
a = 
    {9x1 cell}

>> b = unique(a{:})
b = 
    'are'
    'hello'
    'how'
    'the'
    'world'
    'you'
```

and then if you want to convert back to a long string again

```
>> sprintf('%s,',b{:})
ans =
    are,hello,how,the,world,you,
```

Although to be honest if I was having to process strings in this way I wouldn't start with them all in one long string.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't use `unique()` properly. It should work well. See example:

```
A = {'one','two','twenty-two','One','two'};
C = unique(A)
```

You will get

```
C = 

    'One'    'one'    'twenty-two'    'two'
```

Comment: An addition to get from a sting to a cell array and back would make this complete.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Probably no need here. OP doesn't ask for this. :)